# How to add a prefix to all actions with ASP.Net MVC URL Routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm trying to write a MapRoute call that will make any route that is prefixed with "json/" prepend "json" to the action's name.
For instance, a route something like this:

```
"json/{controller}/{action}"
```

with "json/Foo/Bar", it should result in:

```
controller = "Foo"
action = "jsonBar"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if it wouldn't be better to include json in the route-data and look it up in the action? i.e. when mapping your route, use something like (for the defaults):

```
new { mode="json", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
```

or map the route as:

```
"{mode}/{controller}/{action}"
```

then access this in the controller:

```
string mode = (string) RouteData.Values["mode"];
```

(or pass it in as an argument)

Other than that, you could potentially write your own route-handler, but that is a lot of work.