# How to add a dynamic prefix to all routing URLs in Asp.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net, url

There is a link on the web page that transmits the selected culture but to each method and controller I have to add the code (example shown below). Are there any other ways to solve this?

I use resource files but will look at other options.

```
//html
@Html.ActionLink("English", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { culture = "en" }, null)


//Controller
public IActionResult Users(string culture)
{
    Lang(culture);
    return View();
}

public void Lang(string culture)
{
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
}

//Startupe
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Home}/{id?}");

        });
```

Comment: Have you got some code already? Are there any docs on routing?

Comment: Much better. Are you asking how to add `{culture}` to every route?

Comment: Some routing systems fix this by allowing the programmer to define "routing groups", and typically these add a prefix to the URL pattern. Does asp.net support that?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833996/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-all-actions-with-asp-net-mvc-url-routing

Comment: Possibly related: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/route-prefix-attribute-routing-mvc/

Comment: By default, url looks like {Controller} / {action} / {id}. I saw many different options for doing what I needed but they were all in older versions of the environment. and in the official documentation I do not have the necessary.

Comment: I've tried to rewrite the question to make it clearer, feel free to keep editing. I have also cast a reopen vote. You need two more, they should be cast presently.